# ¿Cómo pasar datos del html a flask, para guardarse en mongoDB?

Tags: html, python, mongodb, flask

Estoy aprendiendo el uso de mongodb con pytHon, utilizando el Framework Flask.
Intento guardar el nombre, sexo y la calificación, después de dar clic en botón **agregar**; después de que realizo esa operación me arroja un error en la página web:

> Method Not Allowed
> The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

He intentado buscar información al respecto, pero no consigo respuestas idóneas, o tal vez estoy realizando una búsqueda equivocada.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import render_template, request
import pymongo

app = Flask(__name__)

MONGO_HOST = "localhost"
MONGO_PUERTO = "27017"
MONGO_TIEMPO_FUERA = 1000

MONGO_URI = "mongodb://"+MONGO_HOST+":"+MONGO_PUERTO+"/"

MONGO_BASEDATOS = "escuela"
MONGO_COLECCION = "alumnos"

try:
    cliente = pymongo.MongoClient(
    MONGO_URI, serverSelectionTimeoutMS=MONGO_TIEMPO_FUERA)
    baseDatos = cliente[MONGO_BASEDATOS]
    coleccion = baseDatos[MONGO_COLECCION]            
    cliente.server_info()
    print("Conexión establecida satisfactoriamente")
    cliente.close
except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError as errorTiempo:
    print("Tiempo excedido"+errorTiempo)
except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure as errorConexion:
    print("Falló al conectarse a la base de datos"+errorConexion)

@app.route("/")
def index():    
    return render_template('empleados/index.html')

@app.route("/registrar")
def registrar():    
   return render_template('empleados/create.html')

@app.route("/store", methods = ['POST'])
def storage():   
    nombre_recibido = request.args['txtNombre']
    sexo_recibido = request.args['txtSexo']
    calificacion_recibido = request.args['txtCalificacion']
    baseDatos.coleccion.insert_one({
        'nombre':nombre_recibido,
        'sexo': sexo_recibido,
        'calificacion': calificacion_recibido
    })    
    return render_template('empleados/create.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**create.html**

```
<form action="" method="post" action="/store" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Nombre:
  <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre">
  <br>
  Sexo:
  <input type="text" name="txtSexo" id="txtSexo">
  <br>
  Calificación:
  <input type="text" name="txtCalificacion" id="txtCalificacion">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Agregar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola estimado Hoffman:

Tienes 2 errores en tu aplicacion:

1. Error
   Por lo general las peticiones de un formulario van a ir directamente a la url cuya función la renderizo en este caso a tu función `registrar`, pero como dicha función no permite el método POST te muestra el error.

   Si lo que deseas hacer es enviar a otro endpoint debes emplear [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.url_for) en el action del form para asignar el endpoint:

```
<form action="{{ url_for("store") }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Nombre:
  <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre">
  <br>
  Sexo:
  <input type="text" name="txtSexo" id="txtSexo">
  <br>
  Calificación:
  <input type="text" name="txtCalificacion" id="txtCalificacion">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Agregar">
</form>
```

---

2. error

Para acceder a los valores enviados desde el formulario debes utilizar `request.form["CAMPO"]` en lugar de `request.args["CAMPO"]`

```
@app.route("/store", methods = ['POST'])
def storage():   
    nombre_recibido = request.form['txtNombre']
    sexo_recibido = request.form['txtSexo']
    calificacion_recibido = request.form['txtCalificacion']
    baseDatos.coleccion.insert_one({
        'nombre':nombre_recibido,
        'sexo': sexo_recibido,
        'calificacion': calificacion_recibido
    })    
    return render_template('empleados/create.html')
```